# D365 Business Central, we need to create records into Items using C# code

Tags: c#, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

We need a requirement to create our own C# WebAPI project that will connect Business Central and inserts/updates data into Items.After doing a search, we found that this is possible using Business Central APIs like given in the link below.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-connect-apps

Here, we are not able to understand,

- How should we connect to Business Central?
- How can we call items API and what the parameters are?
- How can we see list of available APIs?
- Why do we need to create other connect apps?

If somebody has the C# code snippet/example please share with us, it will be really helpful for us.

OR Are there any SDKs available same as like CRM SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

How should we connect to Business Central?

If you are talking about connecting it to BC using code then you will need the Username and Web Access key of the Business Central user, which is different from the AAD user credentials.

How can we call items API and what the parameters are?

Please find the below sample code which might help you to understand how to call APIs

```
    string url = "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/<<Your Environment Name>>/api/v1.0/companies(<<GUID of the company for which item/items needs to be retrieved/added/updated>>)/items";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    String username = "<<UserName>>";
    String password = "<<WebAccessKey>>";
    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

    //Get Request for all Items
    HttpRequestMessage readRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    readRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    HttpResponseMessage readResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(readRequest).Result;
    string content = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(readResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
    {
        content = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Get Request for a specific Item

    string specificItemURl = url + "(<<Guid of the item to be reteieved>>)";
    HttpRequestMessage readSpecificRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, specificItemURl);
    readSpecificRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    HttpResponseMessage readSpecificResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(readSpecificRequest).Result;
    string specificItem = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader streamSpecificItem = new StreamReader(readSpecificResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
    {
        specificItem = streamSpecificItem.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Create Request
    string jsonObject = "{'number':'18962-S','displayName':'ATHENS Desk 3','type':'Inventory','itemCategoryId':'6d4e5f4d-8ad1-ea11-bb85-000d3a2a9e6e','itemCategoryCode':'TABLE','blocked':false,'baseUnitOfMeasureId':'354f6647-8ad1-ea11-bb85-000d3a2a9e6e','gtin':'','unitPrice':1000.8,'priceIncludesTax':false,'unitCost':780.7,'taxGroupId':'fc4c5f4d-8ad1-ea11-bb85-000d3a2a9e6e','taxGroupCode':'FURNITURE','baseUnitOfMeasure':{'code':'PCS','displayName':'Piece','symbol':null,'unitConversion':null}}";
    HttpRequestMessage createRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);  
    createRequest.Content = new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    createRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    HttpResponseMessage createResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(createRequest).Result;
```

How can we see list of available APIs?

You will need to login into the Business Central instance with a user who has Administration role. After logging in Click on Services from the ribbon and then select Web Services. You should able to view all the api endpoints.

Hope this helps you in what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: Thanks Shivkant, actually this code is giving an error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.". Could you please help me resolve the same?

Comment: WEB API URL is configured for https and will require TLS 1.2. Below are the registry entries that you should check for in your machine and if not present request you to create them.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
      "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
      "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
      "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
      "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001

Comment: it is something like, we are have created a WebAPI project and going to upload at Azure, so we cannot use this Registry change solution.

Comment: Can you try this statement before creating the HttpClient, System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Yes, I tried, Thanks for reply, The error has changed now,

Comment: I have passed the user name and web access key (generated in BC)

Comment: does the user has Administration role in BC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220918/discussion-between-shivkant-soni-and-inkey-solutions).

Comment: Let me know if generating the new Web Access Key resolved your authorization issue, looks like you left the chat and could not reach you. Also it might be helpful for others if you mark an answer which resolved your issue/query by up-voting/verifying it.